# JSP Default cursor location

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jsp-tags

Once this `JSP` page load if I press "Enter" button is clicks "Select Work Item" button i.e `first div tag`, I want to disable it. I do not want any action to be done when I press "Enter" but it should work when I click using mouse.

```
<table border="0"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="95%" class="DataTable">
            <tr>
              <td width="30%" >
                <div align="Center">
                  <a Href=""  OnMouseOut="isimgact( 'btSelectWorkItm',0)" OnMouseOver="isimgact( 'btSelectWorkItm',1)" onclick ="return fnSubmitWorkList( document.template,'<%=workList.getNoOfChkBoxes()%>','selectWI','TWL','WorkList');">
                    <img src="<%=PAGEBUTTON%>/SelectWorkItm.gif" name= "btSelectWorkItm" alt="Select Work Item" tabindex="10" width="165" height="25" style="CURSOR: hand" border="0" ondrop="fnDrop()" ondragover="fnOverDrag()">
                  </a>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td width="30%">
                <div align="Center">
                  <a Href=""  OnMouseOut="isimgact( 'btTnfToTeamUsr',0)" OnMouseOver="isimgact( 'btTnfToTeamUsr',1)" onclick ="return fnSubmitWorkList( document.template,'<%=workList.getNoOfChkBoxes()%>','transferTU','TWL','WorkItemRout');">
                    <img src="<%=PAGEBUTTON%>/TnfToTeamUsr.gif" name= "btTnfToTeamUsr" alt="Transfer To User" tabindex="10" width="165" height="25" style="CURSOR: hand" border="0" ondrop="fnDrop()" ondragover="fnOverDrag()">
                  </a>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td width="30%">
                <div align="Center">
                  <a Href=""  OnMouseOut="isimgact( 'btTnfToSite',0)" OnMouseOver="isimgact( 'btTnfToSite',1)" onclick ="return fnSubmitWorkList( document.template,'<%=workList.getNoOfChkBoxes()%>','transferTS','TWL','WorkItemRout');">
                    <img src="<%=PAGEBUTTON%>/TnfToSite.gif" name= "btTnfToSite" alt="Transfer To Site" tabindex="10" width="165" height="25" style="CURSOR: hand" border="0"  ondrop="fnDrop()" ondragover="fnOverDrag()">
                  </a>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add a JavaScript onload method to keep the focus elsewhere.

Comment: Have you any input that could take the focus ? PS : this could be a feature that advanced user might like, using the mouse is not the only way to use a application, even a WebApp. `tab` and `enter` should not be touch to much

Comment: No I do not have any input which take the focus

Comment: shi could you please tell me how to change focus

Answer (score 0):

```html
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
 var ev = (typeof event!= 'undefined') ? window.event : e;
 if(ev.keyCode == 13 && document.activeElement.id == "button_id") {
  return false;//disable enter
 }
}
```

Comment: return false is not doing anything , it still click on button and page is redirecting to new page.

Answer (score 0):

try this once in your JS file

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function stopRKey(evt) { 
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;} 
} 

document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 

</script>
```

Comment: return false is not doing anything , it still click on button and page is redirecting to new page.